# Specific sudo-shell command takes up to 20 minutes

Tags: ssh, sudo, google-cloud-platform

I'm running multiple LEMP stacks on Google Compute Cloud infrastructure. All VM's are identical to eachother when initiated and I've got this weird issue with one of them. Whenever I run this command, it can sometimes take up to 20 minutes to finish:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
```

I run this in the /public_html/ folder where the CMS is located. Whenever I run it in 'parts', so only `find` or `chmod` it's pretty much instantly. While this command is running and I open another instance to see the `top` results, this is the output:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                             
23946 root      20   0  141560 134128   1944 S  39.6  1.8   8:43.19 find
```

I've checked all the 'my sudo commands are slow' solutions like correcting the hostname, restarting various services etc; but the problem doesn't appear to be the sudo command, it's only this specific combo. Why is that? What could be wrong?

Note: I've got multiple VMs running with about the same system in size and folder structure. On there I can run the same command in about 10 seconds. Sure this specific instance might be a bit bigger but no way 2000% bigger..

Comment: you could try `sudo chmod -R u+rX .` Bit X will only set execute on directories, or if already set.

Comment: don't sudo everything, set it up so that you own the files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, running the command verbose, that the session files in `/var/sessions` where running in the tens of thousands. Applying the fix as ctrl-alt-delor suggested to only change the permissions where needed helped a lot to speed the process up.